# Python/Django: How to convert utf-16 str bytes to unicode?

Tags: python, django, unicode, encoding, utf-16

Fellows,

I am unable to parse a unicode text file submitted using django forms. Here are the quick steps I performed:

1. Uploaded a text file ( encoding: utf-16 ) ( File contents: `Hello World 13` )
2. On server side, received the file using `filename = request.FILES['file_field']`
3. Going line by line: `for line in filename: yield line`
4. `type(filename)` gives me `<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>`
5. `type(line)` is `<type 'str'>`
6. `print line` : `'\xff\xfeH\x00e\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00 \x00W\x00o\x00r\x00l\x00d\x00 \x001\x003\x00'`
7. `codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE == line[:2]` returns `True`
8. **Now**, I want to re-construct the unicode or ascii string back like "Hello World 13" so that I can parse the integer from line.

One of the ugliest way of doing this is to retrieve using `line[-5:]` (= `'\x001\x003\x00'`) and thus construct using `line[-5:][1]`, `line[-5:][3]`.

I am sure there must be better way of doing this. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`codecs.iterdecode()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.iterdecode) to decode the object on the fly:

```
from codecs import iterdecode

for line in iterdecode(filename, 'utf16'): yield line
```